# MS Graph API: What is subscription ID max length?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, subscription

What is MS Graph "subscription id" property max length?
In examples length of id is 36 characters (e.g. "7f105c7d-2dc5-4530-97cd-4e7ae6534c07").
It will be always like this? I can't find info in documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation doesn't explicitly states it is an UUID... though it certainly looks line one, probably will be one, and will most likely always be one. However, imho, unless you really have problems in terms of storage, it is best to reserve a reasonable size and assume this ID is a "opaque string" that you just store, and assume is unique (so you can make some key of it, or build an index on it, if you would be referring to a database as the storage). If there are other reasons why you need to know the side, please clarify...

Comment: Thanks for answer and advices! You are right, I'm asking because of storage optimization. 
I don't think they will change identifier format, because everywhere they use format of UUID for any ID. Thus, I'll store this UUID as CHAR(36) in my DB to have better performace. Thanks again!